# I use go_route and i want keep Navigation rail appears in all app screens

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I created the side navigation bar (NavigationRail), and i use go_route to navigate ,the problem that when I push to another screen inside any navigation rail item the NavigationRail disappear, so is there any way to keep navigation rail in screen even after navigate to another screens inside the same navigation rail item?